# Create column that tracks number of cycles each subject completes

Tags: r, cumulative-sum

I'm working with a data set that counts the number of visits a subject makes to certain locations (or types of locations). When a subject visits a certain location (in my example, we'll say it's location "X"), the visit count resets for each subject.

I have a grouping variable that helps me filter between "X" and "non-X" locations, but I want to track the number of sequences that occur for each subject.

```
library(dplyr)
location <- c("A", "B", "X", "A", "C", "X", "A", "X", "C", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "X") 
group <- c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)
id <- c(111, 111, 111, 111, 112, 112, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 114, 114, 114, 114)

df <- data.frame(id, group, location)

df <- within(df, {
    ## this produces a lot of warnings, but it achieves my desired result
    count = ave(id, group, cumsum(group == 0), id, FUN = seq)
    }) %>%
    mutate(count = ifelse(group == 0, yes = 0, no = count)) ## mark restarts

print(df)
     id location group count
 1  111        A     1     1
 2  111        B     1     2
 3  111        X     0     0
 4  111        A     1     1
 5  112        C     1     1
 6  112        X     0     0
 7  113        A     1     1
 8  113        X     0     0
 9  113        C     1     1
10  113        A     1     2
11  113        B     1     3
12  114        B     1     1
13  114        A     1     2
14  114        A     1     3
15  114        X     0     0
```

Thanks to stackoverflow, I've found the code I needed to generate sequences within each of the subjects in my data. However, this only keeps a running count of each individual event of the data. I'd like to be able to record how many times the count resets in each subject's data, and preserve this as a variable to help with other analyses.

I've been struggling with how to correctly describe what I've needed, and generating sequences like this hasn't been something I've had experience with programming-wise. I'm working with several hundred-thousand IDs, so I'm reluctant to try and tuck any of these operations inside a for loop in R. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this in a more straightforward and R-friendly way?

Here's an example of what I'm hoping to get to:

```
     id location group count cycle
 1  111        A     1     1     1
 2  111        B     1     2     1
 3  111        X     0     0     0
 4  111        A     1     1     2
 5  112        C     1     1     1
 6  112        X     0     0     0
 7  113        A     1     1     1
 8  113        X     0     0     0
 9  113        C     1     1     2
10  113        A     1     2     2
11  113        B     1     3     2
12  114        B     1     1     1
13  114        A     1     2     1
14  114        A     1     3     1
15  114        X     0     0     0
```

This function returns what I'm looking for, but I'm not sure it will scale well to the actual data:

```
trackCycle <- function(sequence) {
    cycle <- 1
    out <- c()
    for (i in 1:length(sequence)) {
        if(i != 1 & sequence[i] == 0) {
            cycle <- cycle + 1
            out <- c(out, 0)
        } else {
            out <- c(out, cycle)
        }
    }
    out
}

df %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(cycle = trackCycle(count))
```

Comment: for each id, you can use `1+cumsum(location=="X")`, and replace the indices where location == "X" with 0.

Comment: @nongkrong, thanks for your quick response! Are you able to elaborate in a comment? I'm not following where your suggestion should be implemented, sorry!

Comment: no problem, I just meant the following `df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(cycle = 1 + cumsum(location=="X"))`.  Then, `df[df$location=="X","cycle"] <- 0` if you want.

Comment: @nongkrong Aha! Thank you very much, that's very easy. I'll edit my post and place your solution in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straightforward solution from the comments:

```
df <- df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(cycle = 1 + cumsum(location == "X"))

df[df$location == "X", "cycle"] <- 0
```